# Issue with c3.js tooltip when rendering negative float values of x

Tags: c3

I am using c3.js for creating a chart and this is an issue I found out. If you have a data point with negative float x value, the tooltip rounds off this value to the nearest integer.

You can try doing this just by changing the data in [this](http://c3js.org/samples/simple_xy.html) example. Just change one of the x values to a negative float value and then hover over that point and notice the value of x reported by the tooltip.

Is there any solution to this, or has anyone faced a similar problem?

Comment: I noticed the same issue can occur to the tick labels on the x-axis. Where -0.5 will be rounded to -1. This caused some of my scatter plots to have adjacent x-axis ticks with the same #/label. For example the scatter plot's x-axis ticks would be: -3, -2, -2, -1, -1, 0, 0.5, 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5

Answer (score 2):

In c3.js look for the following function:

```
Axis.prototype.getXAxisTickFormat = function getXAxisTickFormat() {
```

Inside this function there is a `format` variable that is causing the negative x-axis values to be rounded.

```
format = $$.isTimeSeries() ? $$.defaultAxisTimeFormat : $$.isCategorized() ? $$.categoryName : function (v) { return v < 0 ? v.toFixed(0) : v; }
```

The line of code above has a ternary operator that checks if the x-axis values are a 'time series' or 'categorized'. In our situation the values are neither so the `format` variable is set to be the following function:

```
function (v) { return v < 0 ? v.toFixed(0) : v; }
```

This function will leave any integer greater than 0 as is but it will round any negative integers to 0 decimal places and convert the integer to a string using [.toFixed(0)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed).

Replace the `format` line with the one I have written below and it will remove the rounding from the negative values:

```
format = $$.isTimeSeries() ? $$.defaultAxisTimeFormat : $$.isCategorized() ? $$.categoryName : function (v) { return v; };
```

I have only tested this today and although I haven't found any issues, there may be a reason why the negative numbers were converted to a string value and if so you may want leave the `format` line as is and just replace the `0` in `.toFixed(0)` with the # of decimals you desire.

[UPDATE] If you don't want to edit the c3.js source code you can also use the format options for tooltips and x/y ticks. See: http://c3js.org/samples/tooltip_format.html

This is a function I use for the y-axis values. It rounds the tick values to 3 decimal places but strips trailing zeros.

```
axis : {
  y:{
    tick: {
      format: function (d) {
        var df = Number( d3.format('.3f')(d) );
        return df;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. This was for a project I was doing 3-4 months back, so I'll check if I still have the code and try it out.